# Python String to Bytes

Tags: python, byte, xbee

I have to pass in a string to xbee:

```
xbee.tx(dest_addr='\x00\x01', data='hello world')
```

I'd like just to input a string or integer like `01`, but then I get the message:
`The data provided for 'dest_addr' was not 2 bytes long`

I'm using Python 2.7

How can this be resolved? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the full traceback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a simple convenience function using the [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) module to convert integer addresses into the binary string format that the xbee module wants (which appears from your example to be big-endian unsigned short):

```
>>> import struct
>>> def make_address(addr):
...     return struct.pack(">H", addr)
...
>>> make_address(1)
'\x00\x01'
```